# global pointer in c language

Tags: variables, pointers

This is my friend question from my instructor about how to print 
main method value of local variable in method function when it's 
variable pushed and pop from stack (because when method function
called it's variable pushed and when it reached to end pop from 
stack) then it's local variable storage back to the memory.

**Why main method print 100 ?**

```
// Define a global pointer
int *ptr;

int method()
{
    // Define a variable local in this method 
    int local = 100;

    // Set address of local variable (name of variable is local) 
    // in the ptr pointer
    ptr = &local;

    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    // Call method
    method();   

    // Print value of ptr pointer
    cout<<*ptr<<"\n";   

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking why the main method is printing 100.

1.The local variable is assigned some memory space. (say at X. Therefore [x]=>100)

2.The pointer which is global is then assigned to the point at X.(say pointers space is Y. [Y]=>X)

3.Therefore the point of the pointer is X.

4.Now you choose to print value of the pointer. i.e. [[y]]=[x] which is 100.

Why is doesn't print a garbage value is because even though the memory space is no longer allocated to local it still contains that value.

If you wrote some more code the point in memory might have been overwritten by another variable

Comment: I think this idea is specific to OS. I saw this behavior in unix.

Comment: Don't think so. I saw this behaviour in windows and as far as I know its just general C concepts